# Wrong content length when sending a file

Tags: python, python-requests

I am having the problem that the `requests` library for some reason is making the payload bigger and causing issues. I enabled http logging, and in in the output I can see the content length being 50569, not 50349, as the actual file size should indicate.

```
send: b'POST /api/1/images HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:8000\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.21.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAc
cept: application/json\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAuthorization: Bearer 28956340ba9c7e25b49085b4d273522b\r\ncontent-type: image/png\r\n
Content-Length: 50569\r\n\r\n'                                                                                                           
send: b'--ac9e15d6d3aa3a77506c2daccca2ee47\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="0007-Alternate-Lateral-Pulldown_back-STEP1"; filename
="0007-Alternate-Lateral-Pulldown_back-STEP1.png"\r\n\r\n\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x08\x06\x00\
x00\x00>U\xe9\x92\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0b\x13\x00\x00\x0b\x13\x01\x00\x9a\x9c\x18\x00\x00FMiTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0
0<?xpacket begin="\xef\xbb\xbf" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>\n<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.5-c021 79.
155772, 2014/01/13-19:44:00        ">\n   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http:
```

Chrome has exactly the same headers when sending this, but the correct content length, so I am assuming this is why my server complains of a invalid image being sent.

This is my code

```
    url = self.server + "/api/1/images";
    headers = self.default_headers()
    headers['content-type'] = 'image/png'

    # neither of these are actually used for anything
    filename = os.path.basename(image)
    field_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

    files = {field_name: (filename, open(image, 'rb'), '')}

    # Post image
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files, timeout = 5.0)
```

As can be seen, I am using the `b` flag when opening the file to preserve the binary content, so it should not change.

File size is 50349

```
$ ls -l 0007-Alternate-Lateral-Pulldown_back-STEP1.png 
-rw-rw-r--@ 1 carlerik  staff  50349 Nov 26  2019 0007-Alternate-Lateral-Pulldown_back-STEP1.png
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [Charles proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to dig into this and I now have gotten to the bottom of this. There are basically two things to note:

1. The difference in content length between the request sent by Chrome and Requests is *exactly* the length of the *boundary fields* (a multipart form concept) *before* and *after* the file + the six CRLF (`\r\n`) sequences + the `Content-Disposition` header.

```
echo '50569-178-36-6' | bc
50349
```

The boundary field looks like this: `--ac9e15d6d3aa3a77506c2daccca2ee47\r\n`
You can also see from the HTTP header and body dump that the header is actually *in the body* and after the boundary field, not as part of the normal headers. This was important and led me on the right path.

2. The second part of the answer is that the guys that wrote the server API I am interfacing with did not understand/read the HTTP spec for the exact bits they ask for: the `Content-Disposition` header.

The API docs for `.../images` state that this header must be present always, as they use (well, *used* in the past) its content to extract filenames and such. The problem is that the way they use it is not in accordance with [how it is intended to be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition): in a *multipart* HTTP request it is part of the body of the HTTP request, describing the part (form field) of the request it precedes.

This is, of course, also how Requests uses it, but I did not have this information before venturing into this abyss, so I was misinformed by the code in the controller that states this in its doc. So I assumed that Requests would put the header in the header section, which it did not, and not the body, which it did. After all, I saw that Chrome "did the right thing", but it turned out that was only because these requests were handcrafted in javascript:

**apiService.js**

```
    /**
     * Upload image
     * @param file
     * @returns {*}
     * @private
     */
    _api.postImage = function (file) {
        if (typeof file != 'object') {
            throw Error('ApiService: Object expected');
        }

        file.fileName = (/(.*)\./).exec(file.name)[1];
        var ContentDisposition = 'form-data; name="' + encodeURI(file.fileName) + '"; filename="' + encodeURI(file.name) + '"';

        return Upload.http({
            url: Routing.generate('api_post_image'),
            headers: {
                'Content-Disposition': ContentDisposition,
                'Content-Type': file.type
            },
            data: file
        });
    };
```

So the `Content-Disposition` header here is basically a proprietary header to convey information about the filename, that shares its appearance with the general in-body header from the spec. That means all it takes to fix this is to create a request with a custom body read from file and set this header.

---

To round this off, this was how it was all simplified down to:

```
headers = dict()
headers['authorization'] = "<something>"
headers['content-type'] = 'image/png'

with open(image, 'rb') as imagefile:
    # POST image
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=imagefile)
```